# How do I make a div with :hover stay in hover state on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question but basically, I have a div with a button with some :hover state in CSS, however, I want that upon clicking the button, it will stay on the hovered state, is this possible?

My Code

```css
#englishbutton {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#F16D71;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition: .3s background-color;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#englishbutton:hover {
    background-color:#F5999C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="actionsection">
        <input name="englishbutton" type="button" id="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH">
</div>
```

I have tried searching for similar questions and one of them said to use :focus state but it does not work, any help would be much appreicated!

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous way to do this:

You can use `:focus`:

```css
#englishbutton {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#F16D71;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition: .3s background-color;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#englishbutton:hover, #englishbutton:focus {
    background-color:#F5999C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="actionsection">
  <input name="englishbutton" type="button" id="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH">
</div>
```

Using `jQuery` you can add the background on `click` of the button using **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method:

```js
$('#englishbutton').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#F5999C');
});
```

```css
#englishbutton {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#F16D71;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition: .3s background-color;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#englishbutton:hover {
    background-color:#F5999C;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actionsection">
  <input name="englishbutton" type="button" id="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH">
</div>
```

Or you can use **[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** method to add a styled active class like this:

```js
$('#englishbutton').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#englishbutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F16D71;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
#englishbutton:hover, #englishbutton.active {
  background-color: #F5999C;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actionsection">
  <input name="englishbutton" type="button" id="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH">
</div>
```

Comment: It's weird, even though it shows that its working using :focus here, it doesn't work in my code. Would there be any reason why that could be happening?

Comment: @EdenChew, maybe in your code you're doing something wrong. Maybe the selector is wrong. Or the `css` for this is overwritten by another `css` rule. It can be many things. Try the code from my answer in a new separate file on the same location you have your project and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
div:active
```

only stay when the mouse is clicked,

use

```
div:focus
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want the appearance to stay after the user clicks elsewhere on the page (an `<input>` element, etc.) you can set a class when the button is clicked, and use that for styling:

```js
var el = $('#englishbutton');

el.click(
  function() {
    el.addClass('clickedbutton');
  }
);
```

```css
#englishbutton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #F16D71;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#englishbutton:hover,
#englishbutton.clickedbutton {
  background-color: #F5999C;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actionsection">
  <input name="englishbutton" type="button" id="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH">
</div>

<input value="Focus here after clicking" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a javascript to change make the hover formatting onclick like

```
<style>
      .englishbutton {
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
      outline: none;
      background-color: #F16D71;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      transition: .3s background-color;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 15px;
     }
     .englishbutton:hover {
     background-color: #F5999C;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<div>
   <input id="button" type="button" class="englishbutton" value="ENGLISH" onclick="var s= document.getElementById('button');
s.style.backgroundColor='#F5999C';x.style.color='#ffffff';
" />
</div>
```